# Python 3.6.3 KeyError

Tags: python-3.6

I want to check for an element exists in a dictionary in O(1) time with a "try/catch" block in python3. When I try to do this I get a syntax error and I am not sure why:

```
try a_dict[i]:
    print(i) 
except KeyError:
    a_dict[i] = ... #some item
```

For simplicity let's say that I have a function that checks for a duplicate in an array and I have this function that's using the logic from above:

```
def hasDuplicate(a):
    a_dict = dict()
    for i in a:
        # logic from above
        try a_dict[i]:
            print(i) 
        except KeyError:
            a_dict[i] = True
        # end of logic from above
    return -1
```

I would get a syntax error from on the line with the try statement.

I want to avoid using `in` because that checks in O(N) time. Unless it checks in O(1) time for a dictionary? Any help or feedback would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
def hasDuplicate(a):
    a_dict = dict()
    for i in a:
        # logic from above
        try:
            print(a_dict[i])
        except KeyError:
            a_dict[i] = True
        # end of logic from above
    return -1
```

From your mention of "try/catch" I guess you are coming from Java? :-)

Comment: Well I would have said "try/except" but that's not as well known. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem! I think try/except is very well known around python devs. Not sure about 'muggles' though!

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because the correct implementation of my question, but it should be noted that @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams answer should be used in any situation checking a hash table

Comment: Agreed. I'm giving @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams +1 too for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to avoid using `in` because that checks in O(N) time. Unless it checks in O(1) time for a dictionary?

It does. Dictionaries are a specialized hashmap, so containment checking is an amortized O(1).

Comment: This is good to know, thank you. It should be noted that though I marked the previous answer as correct, this answer should be used in any situation checking a hash table since ```in``` is in fact O(1) for python dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do? And if you want to find Duplicate there is no need to use try/catch.

```
def hasDuplicate(a):
    a_dict = dict()
    for i in a:
      # logic from above
      try:
        if a_dict[i]:
          print(i) 
      except KeyError:
        a_dict[i] = True
      # end of logic from above
    return -1


print(hasDuplicate([1, 2, 3, 4, 1])) //print duplicate value (i.e. 1 and will return -1)
```